# Gnuplot---clustered rowstacked bars

Tags: plot, gnuplot

How can I make clustered rowstacked bars in gnuplot? It know how to get a clustered bars, but
not a cluster of rowstacked bars. Thanks!

Edit: in a cluster, stacked bars should use different colors/patterns as well.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to have horizontal bars instead of vertical?

Comment: No, why do you think so? I want vertical stacked bars that are clustered for some value on x-axis. For example, for value "A" on x-axis, I want two stacked bars.

Comment: I didn't get the meaning of 'rowstacked', I get the point now, no soluion however.

Comment: Note that I removed the inapproriate tag [tag:cluster-analysis] (which is a complex statistical technique) in favor of just [tag:plot].
In your case, "clustering" is not analysis. It's just "grouping" by some *predefined* criterion. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis for background on cluster analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure how to go about doing this, but, one idea is to make it so that the boxes are touching each other

```
`set boxwidth 1`
```

That doesn't quite get you a "clustered" look yet -- To get a clustered look, I think you'd need to insert a row (maybe column) of zeros...(I haven't sorted through that one in my head yet) into your datafile where you want a cluster break.

Of course, you wouldn't need to set the boxwidth either I suppose...clustered just depends on the breaking every once in a while...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the original post right, it should be easy to accomplish with gnuplot if you can preprocess your data to offset x coordinates of specific data series.

To illustrate the approach I will use the following data in 3 data series:

```
# impulse.dat
0.9 1
1.9 4
2.9 3
3.9 5


1.0 1
2.0 2
3.0 4
4.0 2


1.1 3
2.1 3
3.1 5
4.1 4
```

Here each series has x-coordinates shifted by `.1`. To plot it I choose impulses of width 10.

```
plot [0:5] [0:6] 'impulse.dat' ind 0 w imp lw 10, \
    'impulse.dat' ind 1 w imp lw 10, \
     'impulse.dat' ind 2 w imp lw 10
```

**Edit:** to combine this with Matt's suggestion to use boxes would definitely be better:

```
set boxwidth 0.1
set fill solid
plot [0:5] [0:6] 'impulse.dat' ind 0 w boxes,\
     'impulse.dat' ind 1 w boxes, \
     'impulse.dat' ind 2 w boxes
```

Following is the picture with impulses.

[image: stacked bar plot w impulses]

Comment: If it is possible to make each of the impulses stacked and that each stacked impuls has a different colors/patterns and thus key, then it would be what I want.

Comment: @bellpeace Alright, I misunderstood the question you asked. There is a rowstacked histogram style in gnuplot. `set style histogram rowstacked
; set style data histograms` should help.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But this is not what I need. I want clustered stacked bars. Concretely, I would like to have clusters where each cluster has stacked bars. And, each bar has its own pattern/color.

Comment: May the "Clusters of Stacked Histograms" by Ethan A. Meritt be it http://www.bmsc.washington.edu/people/merritt/

Comment: I believe this is it! Thanks!

Comment: New URL for the resource Dmitri mentions earlier: http://skuld.bmsc.washington.edu/people/merritt/gnuplot/